# Timer-Class should call Methods after some Time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have a lot of classes that try to write something into a database when i start my Wildfly-Server.
It happens that the database is not deployed in the first place and then i get a lot of HTTPNotFound Exceptions.

Because i have a lot classes i dont wanted duplicated Code and wanted to write a helper Class "TimerHelper", where i give him for example a method and say "Try that method, if you get an exception, wait some time and try again"

Some PseudoCode:

```
public class TimerHelper extends TimerTask{
Object o;

public TimerHelper(Object o){
  this.o = o;
}

public boolean startTask(){
try{
  o.start();
}catch(Exception e){
  this.wait(200);
  o.start();
  }
 }
}
```

The Class that wants to write into database:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Motor{

@PostConstruct
 public void init(){
  TimerHelper timer = new TimerHelper(this);
 } 

 public void start(){
   database.write("foobar");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for the problem:

```
public class TimerHelper extends TimerTask {


Callable<Void> task;
private Timer timer;
long delay;

public TimerHelper(Callable<Void> task) {
    timer = new Timer();
    delay = 500;
    this.task = task;
    run();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    if (delay < 3600000) {

        try {
            task.call();
            timer.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            delay = delay + delay;
            timer.schedule(new TimerHelper(task), delay);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            timer.cancel();
        } catch (TimeLimitExceededException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Example Task:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartUp {

@PostConstruct
public void addSfaApi() {
    TimerHelper timer = new TimerHelper(new SfaAPI());
}

class SfaAPI implements Callable<Void> {

    @Override
    public Void call() throws ResourceRepositoryException {
        addSomethingToDatabase();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you want to call a method on a subclass within the run() for your timer but you only have object and not the correct type? If so, then you could make the helper generic, and always pass a type T to it. That way, the method on the object of type T is guaranteed available. Here is a simplistic example of a timer helper that accepts any object that extends TimerTask and calls run() and wait() until the run() method on the contained timer task succeeds. Again, I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve.

```
 import java.util.TimerTask;

class TimerHelper<T extends TimerTask> extends TimerTask {

    T timer = null;

    public TimerHelper(T timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubTimer sub = new SubTimer();
        TimerHelper<TimerTask> t = new TimerHelper<TimerTask>(sub);
        t.run();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            timer.run();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            try {
                e.printStackTrace();
                wait(1000);
                run();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            }
        }
    }

    static class SubTimer extends TimerTask {
        int x = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (x++ < 3)
                throw new RuntimeException("try again");
            System.out.println("do something, finally!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was the right direction.I needed an universal Class which i could give a Task and it would run it periodically if it fails one time.
I solved my problem, but thx very much for your effort.
Will post my Solution